# Remove child XML node from parent with where clause

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, linq, linq-to-xml

Really new to LINQ and XML. I was hoping someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong in trying to remove a child node from an XElement.

Here is a sample of my XML:
(I am trying to remove the "Relation" that corresponds to the user selected relation)

```
<Bill>
  <Element>
    <Name>AccountNumber</Name>
    <Regex></Regex>
    <Left></Left>
    <Right></Right>
    <Top></Top>
    <Bottom></Bottom>
    <Index>0</Index>
    <Relations></Relations>
  </Element>
  <Element>
    <Name>BillDate</Name>
    <Regex></Regex>
    <Left></Left>
    <Right></Right>
    <Top></Top>
    <Bottom></Bottom>
    <Index>1</Index>
    <Relations>
      <Relation>AccountNumber.RightOf.Right.0</Relation>
      <Relation>AccountNumber.Below.Top.-10</Relation>
      <Relation>AccountNumber.Above.Bottom.-10</Relation>
    </Relations>
  </Element>
```

if my WPF GUI, When a user clicks delete on a relation, I want to remove only that relation from the parent.

This is one of the many things I have tried:

```
private void DeleteButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    List<RelationsDetailView> details = (List<RelationsDetailView>)DetailsView.ItemsSource;

    XElement parentElement = (from Node in ocrVar.Xml.Descendants("Element")
                              where Node.Element("Index").Value == ocrVar.SelectedItem.Index.ToString()
                              select Node).FirstOrDefault();
    XElement child = parentElement.Element("Relations").Elements("Relation").Where(xel => xel.Element("Relation").Value == (details[DetailsView.SelectedIndex].Relation)).FirstOrDefault();
    child.Remove();
    ocrVar.Xml.Save(ocrVar.xmlPath);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Where` predicate is incorrect. `xel` is already the `<relation>` element, so you don't have to call`Element("Relation")` again.

You should also replace `XElement.Value` with `(string)XElement` to prevent `NullReferenceException`.

```
.Where(xel => (string)xel == (details[DetailsView.SelectedIndex].Relation))
```

Or you can use `FirstOrDefault` with predicate instead of `Where().FirstOrDefault()` chain:

```
XElement child = parentElement.Element("Relations").Elements("Relation").FirstOrDefault(xel => (string)xel == details[DetailsView.SelectedIndex].Relation);
```

Comment: Perfect, Thanks for explaining it. Also, the bit of advice about preventing the NullReferenceException is great.

Comment: You're welcome. You can also cast `XElement` to `int` and change your first query condition to `where (int)Node.Element("Index")== ocrVar.SelectedItem.Index`

Comment: Good call. I'm assuming it's better to cast something to an int and compare ints than the cast the other as a string and compare two strings? Just curious.

Comment: Quick question.. When calling child.Remove() or child.RemoveNodes() it doesn't behave quite like I thought it would. Instead of removing the entire node (<Relation>AccountNumber.Below.Top.-10</Relation>) it is instead replacing it with what appears to be an empty node (<Relation />). Why is that? and is there a way to remove it all? Thanks

Comment: It should definitely remove the entire element.

Comment: Figured it out. Saving the second query to "child" and then calling child.Remove() left part of the tag there. simply saying "parentElement.Element("Relations").Elements("Relation").FirstOrDefault(xel => (string)xel == details[DetailsView.SelectedIndex].Relation).Remove();" fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

```
xel.Element("Relation").Value == (details[DetailsView.SelectedIndex].Relation
```

This condition always return false, maybe you want something like this?

```
(string)xel.Element("Relation") == (details[DetailsView.SelectedIndex].Relation.ToString())
```

Comment: Quick question.. When calling child.Remove() or child.RemoveNodes() it doesn't behave quite like I thought it would. Instead of removing the entire node (<Relation>AccountNumber.Below.Top.-10</Relation>) it is instead replacing it with what appears to be an empty node (<Relation />). Why is that? and is there a way to remove it all? Thanks